# How to calculate the heterogeneity of a variable which is divided into three separate columns in R

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I have the variable proportion of vegetation height for each transect in a field study, which is categorized into vegetation below 5cm, between 5 and 15cm, and over 15cm. Since each measure is a proportion, when they are added they add up to 100 (except some cases which have to do with the experimental design).

```
df <- structure(list(vegunder5cm = c(37.4, 29.0153846153846, 43.2753623188406, 
36, 29.622641509434, 47.28, 17.8, 3, 26.3114754098361, 0), vegbw5and15cm = c(43.4, 
14.9076923076923, 25.5507246376812, 23.9090909090909, 24.0377358490566, 
13.56, 30.4, 28.2, 19.0327868852459, 30), vegover15cm = c(19.2, 
56.0769230769231, 31.1739130434783, 40.0909090909091, 46.3396226415094, 
39.16, 51.8, 66.55, 54.655737704918, 70), mean_height = c(9.09, 
11.3530769230769, 9.39492753623188, 10.2045454545455, 10.8358490566038, 
9.594, 11.7, 13.2506393861893, 11.4172131147541, 13.5)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to determine which transects have greater heterogeneity in vegetation height and which are more even, though I'm not sure of the proper function for this. I was thinking of calculating the standard deviation of the mean but am not sure how to do this across columns. The mean would be the same anyway (33.33).

Comment: If you had the unaggregated data, standard deviation (within each transect) would be a great idea to measure the spread. By unaggregated I mean, not summarized to proportions, for example raw counts. Do you have access to the original counts per transect?

Comment: Actually, upon further thinking, I realize your situation is special because you have binned data (<5, 5-15, >15). If you had the actual heights of each plant, the standard deviation would be a great idea. But you do not have the actual heights, you only have information of the order of heights, so the data is called "ordinal". The only measure of spread for ordinal data I know is the interquartile range, and it does not really work when you have only three categories. Maybe head to stats.stackexchange.com and ask over there, what is the appropriate measure of spread for my situation.

Comment: What is `mean_height`? Also, is each row one unit of your analysis, that is _transect_ (unfamiliar with your domain)? I ask since there is no unique identifier in data frame.

Comment: Thanks uke, I'll try over there. Parfait - I actually didn't mean to include mean_height. That's a remnant from a previous attempt at analysis on these vegetation heights (essentially choosing the middle height for each category: 2.5 cm, 10 cm, 15cm, etc.)